# REST Call from Scala

Tags: scala, rest

How to make REST Call on `HTTP` from one Scala project to other scala projects API's. which are may be POST or GET with request parameters in Json format.

Answer (score 4):

Full example with JSON (using akka 2.4.4 and spray json ):

```
class Test (implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem) extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  private implicit val exampleFormat = jsonFormat2(Example)

  private implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val endpoint = "http://api.example.com/abc"

  private case class Example(var1: Int, var2: String)

  private def createRequest(example: Example): HttpRequest =
    HttpRequest(
      method = HttpMethods.POST,
      uri = endpoint,
      entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, example.toJson.toString),
      headers = Seq()
    )

  Http().singleRequest(createRequest(Example(213, "test"))
}
```

imports:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import scala.concurrent.Future
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import scala.collection.immutable.Seq
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the Akka HTTP client (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/client-side/index.html)

```scala
val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
  Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://akka.io"))
```

For JSON support, you can use Spray:

- http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/common/json-support.html
- https://github.com/spray/spray-json

Comment: Thanks #devkat I will look into this.